# Julia DataFrames filtering from multiple columns

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to filter a DataFrame on multiple values from different columns. I wrote the following code, but it's giving me an error, `ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (BitArray{1}) used in boolean context`.

```
df[((df.eruption .== "CC2011") && (df.dataset .== "MODIS.NDVI.CDI")), :]
```

Where `eruption` and `dataset` are columns in the dataframe

Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the conditions with the `&` operator and putting each condition in brackets `()`.

```py
df[ ( df.eruption .== "CC2011" ) .& ( df.dataset .== "MODIS.NDVI.CDI" ), :]
```

Comment: add `.` before `&` and `==` and `, :` is needed as column selector.

Comment: This can also be combined with `@view` to be more computationally efficient (although depending on what you're planning to do with the result afterwards you might still have to `copy()`)

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the answer by Sankios there are the following alternatives:

```
filter(row -> row.eruption == "CC2011" && row.dataset == "MODIS.NDVI.CDI", df)
```

and (faster but more verbose):

```
filter([:eruption, :dataset] => (x, y) -> x == "CC2011" && y == "MODIS.NDVI.CDI", df)
```

and soon (in DataFrames.jl 1.0 release) you will be able to write:

```
subset(df, :eruption => ByRow(==("CC2011")), :dataset => ByRow(==("MODIS.NDVI.CDI")))
```